# ps2pdf - force/keep plain text

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

How to use `ps2pdf` and force it to keep plain text if the original pdf contains real text?

Sometimes if a PDF has some areas with background colors it convert the whole pdf to an image!?

How to force [`ps2pdf`](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Ps2pdf.htm) to keep plain text?

Syntax:

```
pdf2ps file.pdf file.pdf.ps
ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dColorImageResolution=50 -dGrayImageResolution=50 file.pdf.ps file_output.pdf
```

PDF example

```
www.bluemachines.dk/pdf_comp/dyn.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer is drive Ghostscript directly, don't use ps2pdf (or pdf2ps).

If you are getting text converted to an image, then its most likely because the original PDF file has transparency, which cannot be represented in PostScript. The only way to deal with that is to render the area of transparency.

There is no way to maintain the Encoding of the text, though in general it won't change. However this is highly dependent on the font and encoding used in the input. I can't say more without seeing an example.

Comment: Have updated my question with a link to a PDF which is converted to an image.. I would really like to use `ps2pf` because it in most cases give the best compressed/optimized output (except when it converts to image) I use two paralleled (gs vs ps2pdf) compressions and use the one with less diskusage

Comment: Using "gs -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=out.ps -dCompressPages=false dyn.pdf" the resulting PostScript file does not contain images. This leads me to suspect that you are using an old version of Ghostscript where the pdf2ps batch file/script uses the pswrite device rather than the ps2write device. Which is one of the reasons I say 'use Ghostscript directly'. You'll get much better control over what you are doing that way, the script is dumb. Why are you converting a PDF file to PostScript and then back to PDF anyway ?

Comment: Have updated the pdf file.. the new one contains a logo with alpha.. If I convert the transparent background to white it works :)

Comment: Here is the reason.. Alot use ps2pdf to reduce the filesize and in some cases the result is better than using ghostscript directly.. http://askubuntu.com/questions/113544/how-to-reduce-pdf-filesize

Comment: Converting the PDF to PostScript and back to PDF again is an excellent way to introduce problems and reduce quality. Saying that using ps2pdf instead of using Ghostscript directly is better is total nonsense, because the ps2pdf script does nothing more than supply command line parameters to Ghostscript.

Comment: Yes your updated PDF file uses transparency (an SMask). As soon as you do that, the PDF is rendered to an image. There is no way to avoid this as the transparency cannot be represented in PostScript. So here's the first example that I mentioned above, converting PDF to PostScript and back to PDF is not a lossless process and can reduce quality.

Comment: I still think `ps2pdf` in some cases really is better than `gs` directly.. If you have large PDF files with alot of styling etc `ps2pdf` reduces the file to almost nothing :) Have created a new question to solve the alpha problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011488/modify-images-in-pdf-with-alpha-channel-and-convert-background-to-white

Comment: Serisouly, there is *nothing* that ps2pdf can be doing, because all it does is collect command line arguments and call Ghostscript. It cannot possibly be doing anything which Ghostscript can't do from the command line (assuming you are using the ps2pdf supplied with GS of course)

Comment: NB You can always run -dNOTRANSPARENCY which will ignore transparency in the input. The output may not be 'correct' but it won't flatten to an image either.